# How to hide Calling UI and make calls with custom UI?

Tags: java, android

I have created a custom ui and making a call using telecom manager for direct dialing. But every time Device default Calling UI is opening.

Here is some code for making calls directly...

```
TelecomManager telecomManager=(TelecomManager)getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("tel", phonenumber, null);
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                extras.putBoolean(TelecomManager.METADATA_IN_CALL_SERVICE_UI, true);
                extras.putBoolean(TelecomManager.EXTRA_PHONE_ACCOUNT_HANDLE,true);
                try {
                    if (telecomManager!=null) {
                        telecomManager.showInCallScreen(true);
                    }
                }catch(SecurityException incoming){
                    incoming.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    if (telecomManager!=null) {
                        telecomManager.placeCall(uri, extras);
                    }
                }catch(SecurityException unlikely){
                    unlikely.printStackTrace();
                }
```

is there a way to hide the default calling ui and use our own calling ui.?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See the [API docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/TelecomManager#placeCall(android.net.Uri,%20android.os.Bundle)) on how to use the placeCall API.  METADATA_IN_CALL_SERVICE_UI should not be passed to placeCall, and EXTRA_PHONE_ACCOUNT_HANDLE is not a boolean extra.  You need to pass in a PhoneAccountHandle.  However, if you're just trying to place a regular mobile call, just omit that extra as the system will pick the right one.

showInCallScreen should also only really be used by the Dialer app to bring its UI to the foreground; its not going to have any impact in your case.

If you want to use your Dialer app as the in-call UI, you need to change it in the system settings.
System Settings --> Apps & Notifications --> Advanced --> Default Apps --> Phone App.  Choose your app there.

To be a default phone app you need to handle the DIAL intent and implement the [InCallService API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/InCallService).